# How to concatenate a default prefix to static properties of a class when getting them

Tags: flutter, dart

I am creating a class in which i have defined static string properties which represent a specific image in the assets folder so i can get the asset path directly instead of typing it manually everywhere. This is the code i've written so far.

```
class AssetImages {
  AssetImages._();
  static const baseDir = '/assets/images/';
  static const logoWhite = '${baseDir}logo_white.png';
  static const access = '${baseDir}access.png';
  static const successful = '${baseDir}successful.png';
  static const unsuccessful = '${baseDir}unsuccessful.png';
}
```

Is there a better way to do this such that i dont have to manually concatenate the baseDir path to each property? An extension of some sorts which would do it automatically

I tried enums but then i will have to create a switch case and check for enum type which would make the code significantly longer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can simplify the process of concatenating the baseDir path to each property using Dart extension methods. By creating an extension for the `String` class, you can add a method that automatically handles the concatenation. Here's how you can do it:

```dart
extension AssetExtension on String {
  String get assetPath => '/assets/images/$this';
}

class AssetImages {
  AssetImages._();
  static final logoWhite = 'logo_white.png'.assetPath;
  static final access = 'access.png'.assetPath;
  static final successful = 'successful.png'.assetPath;
  static final unsuccessful = 'unsuccessful.png'.assetPath;
}
```

With this approach, you can directly call `.assetPath` on any string representing the specific image name, and it will automatically concatenate the baseDir path to it. This way, you eliminate the need to manually concatenate the paths for each property. The resulting code becomes more concise and easier to maintain.